# Convert C# Encoding SHA256 code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encode

Currently I have a request to convert to following C# code to use in JS environment. This piece of code is given by client and we need to use in JS code

```
string pin = "1234";
string authtoken = "abcde12345";    
        var bPass = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}{1}", auth_token, pin));

        using (HashAlgorithm ssp = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA256"))
        {
            var digest = ssp.ComputeHash(bPass);

            return BitConverter.ToString(digest); //e.g. 7B-BB-85-7C-FF-0C-17-74-9F-C2-15-32-5B-CF-E8-16-62-7E-81-97-B0-5D-D5-36-76-B9-A9-F7-F1-F4-9D-CB
        }
```

The above code is to merge authtoken and pin for encoding and create SHA256 hash algorithm.

I'm quite new to encoding in JS so I'm not sure what are the alternatives and correct method to perform the above in JS so that I can get the same result from the C# function.

Please provide me some links and idea to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [CryptoJs](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js).

Taken from their docs:

`var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Message");`

To encode the result as base64, use enc:

```
var base64hash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm manage to solve this and posted the full code in another post of mine using CryptoJS, many thanks to Daniel Nachtrub for the wonderful suggestion.

Here's the link:
[C# SHA256 ComputeHash result different with CryptoJS SHA256 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984198/c-sharp-sha256-computehash-result-different-with-cryptojs-sha256-function/36026310#36026310)